Can we provide an example that the adjacency matrix of a directed graph $G$ ($d$ regular digraph) is not symmetric?
For $1\le d \le n$ an undirected (resp. directed) graph $G$ is called $d$-regular if every vertex has exactly $d$ neighbours (rest. $d$ in-neighbors and $d$ out-neighbours). For a digraph $G$  with $n$ vertices its adjacency matrix $\mu_{ij}$ is defined by $\mu_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ otherwise it is $0$.
It is clear that the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph $G$ is symmetric. However, can we provide an example that the adjacency matrix of a directed graph $G$ ($d$ regular digraph) is not symmetric? I try to draw a graph with $4$ vertices and $d=2$ but its adjacency matrix is still symmetric...

I can give that example in three vertices with three directed edges, Steve.  (Cultural referent: Name That Tune.)

How about a graph with 4 vertices such that the edges go from 1 to 2,3, 2 to 3,4, 3 to 4,1 and 4 to 1,2? You have $\mu_{12}=1$ but $\mu_{21}=0$.
